# New [Scientific-Notation] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

I'm a bit new to meta, but I recently posted a [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150402/help-me-with-my-chemistry-hw)
and it requires converting to and from scientific-notation. I almost created a scientific-notation tag, but I'm not sure if I would be justified in doing so. I did a little [research](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/02/02fc367feb457aa667d6b02af0a1e29ba9244ba868004affd31f817b3dc6b373.jpg) and found <s>around 10</s> 4 other questions that could be reasonably tagged [scientific-notation].

- [Q1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71265/efficient-scientific-notation)
- [Q2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124192/help-me-golf-my-numbers)
- [Q3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123435/general-tips-for-representing-large-numbers/123437#123437)
- [Q4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91009/evaluate-expressions-with-significant-figures)

Should I create it or not? Also, any constructive explanation on the process of creating tags would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, any constructive explanation on the process of creating tags would be appreciated.

Asking on meta is a good first step before creating a tag. We generally discuss tag creations here first. However, providing a list of applicable challenges and posting some suggestions for the scope of the tag are really helpful for starting a constructive discussion.

As for your specific suggestion, in general it seems like a good idea. The scope is a more important question here. It's probably not worth tagging every challenge which *allows* input or output in scientific notation. Instead, we should probably use the tag for challenges which are specifically *about* manipulating scientific notation. But even then we should be careful to make a distinction between the new tag and the existing [floating-point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-point).

So I'd suggest you add those challenges you have in mind into your question so we have something more concrete to discuss. I'll edit my answer accordingly then.

Comment: I wasn't considering tagging them scientific-notation, but I suppose that would be in order